# Setting credential in Ansible Tower GUI

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I chose credential type as 'Machine'.

What are the required parameters for the Username and Password fields to set up a bare-minimum credential.
Upon trying multiple times, I get :

Enter passphrase for /tmp/awx_1977135_t5pmrI/credential_4343:

with no option to input anything.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create Username and Password.  You can also provide the privilege escalation method(for eg: sudo).
Make sure the password is in encrypted format.It is mentioned in the known issues

```
If your Tower server has a version of OpenSSH that predates 5.7, jobs will fail when launched jobs with ECDSA credentials.

If the key is unencrypted, your job will fail with a message similar to:
Enter passphrase for /tmp/ansible_tower_RcQweY/tmph9Jote:
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.0/html/release-notes/known_issues.html

You can also try to delete the one which you created and create from scratch.